# How do I hide rows in a Google spreadsheet using a script based on a character in a column?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using the below script to hide all rows with a value of "1" in column B.

```
function myfunction () {
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("CSSMaster");
  var maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();

  //show all the rows
  sheet.showRows(1, maxRows);

  //get data from clumn B
  var data = sheet.getRange('B:B').getValues();

  //iterate over all rows
  for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++){
    //compare first character, if 1, then hide row
    if(data[i][0].charAt(0) == '1'){
      sheet.hideRows(i+1);
    }
  }
}
}
```

I go to my spreadsheet and enter the following: =myfunction(B:B) , I see "thinking" but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong? (I'm VERY new to Google scripts and am guessing this is a very basic error.)

Comment: Try reading up on the onEdit() trigger: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers

Comment: Thanks! I read through this and I don't seem to be violating any of the rules that would make the script not work. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Your instincts are right - it's a very basic error. First, make sure that you're actually running the code you intend to.

In this example, you've got a function inside a function. When you invoke `myFunction()` from the spreadsheet, execution will begin but won't find any code to run. Because `onOpen()` is enclosed in `myFunction()`, but there is no call in `myFunction()` to `onOpen()`, there's nothing to do.

Sort that out - you probably just need to get rid of the declaration and closing brace for `onOpen()`.

Next, you're passing a 2-dimensional array of values when you invoke `myFunction(B:B)`, but you have no parameter handing in the function. (You retrieve the values explicitly with `getRange('B:B').getValues()`.)

General advice: learn some JavaScript (I recommend CodeAcademy), and try your hand at some of the [Google Apps Script tutorials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles?csw=1). With the competence and confidence from those, you should have no problem getting this working on your own.