# Hide Rows Based on Content of a Cell - Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to create a way to hide a certain number of rows if there is a certain value in a cell of a Google spreadsheet.

### E.g.

```
         A                   B
1   Include All options`?       Yes/No
2   Option A:                   Yes/No
3   Option B:                   Yes/no
etc.
```

If cell B1 is "yes" there is no need to look at all other options.  However, if they select "No", there needs to be an option for selecting the Option "Yes/No".  For this reason, I would like to hide the rows when option = yes but unhide them if it is No

Comment: please read how to post here. You cant post a spec and expect someone to code it.

Comment: Also its a dup of others like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20383874/how-do-i-hide-rows-in-a-google-spreadsheet-using-a-script-based-on-a-character-i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code detects whether a certain cell (B3) was edited, then hides a couple of rows under that row (row 3) if it was edited:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  Logger.log('e.value: ' + e.value);

  var cellEdited = e.range.getA1Notation();
  Logger.log('cellEdited: ' + cellEdited);

  if (cellEdited === "B3") {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var theSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

    theSheet.hideRows(4, 2);
  };
}
```

This code uses a function name of `onEdit()`, which means that it monitors the spreadsheet for edits to a cell.  If there is an edit, the function runs.  This is a "simple" trigger.  There are also installable triggers for monitoring the spreadsheet.

Note the `Logger.log()` statements.  These statement print information to the LOGS which you can VIEW from the VIEW, LOGS menu.

### For your purposes:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  Logger.log('e.value: ' + e.value);

  var cellEdited = e.range.getA1Notation();
  Logger.log('cellEdited: ' + cellEdited);

  if (cellEdited === "B1" && e.value === "yes") {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var theSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

    theSheet.hideRows(2, 2);
  };
}
```